# Program to Armstrong Number of 'n' digits is giving wrong output for only 153

Tags: c

My program to check Armstrong Number of 'n' digits is giving a wrong output, only when the input is 153.

Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int p, k, n, t, sum, n1, m;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    n1=n;
    for(p=0, k=1; n/k>=1; ++p, k*=10);
    printf("\nThe number of digits: %d", p);

    for(sum=0; n>0; n/=10)
    {
        t= n%10;
        printf("\n\nThe base and power: %d and %d", t, p);
        m=pow(t, p);
        printf("\nThe calculated no is: %d", m);
        sum+=pow(t, p);
        printf("\nThe sum is: %d", sum);
    }

    printf("\n\t The original number is  : %d", n1);
    printf("\n\t The calculated number is: %d", sum);

    if(n1==sum)
        printf("\n\t%d is an armstrong number\n", n1);
    else
        printf("\n\t%d is not an armstrong number\n", n1);

    return 0;
}
```

The program is getting **152** when it does the math and is therefore giving a wrong output.  I have printed every step to find the exact point of error.

- I have used power function instead of for loops
- I cannot use t* t*t as this program is for Armstrong numbers of "n" digits, and not only 3
- I am compiling the program using Code Blocks 16.01

**The problem is, it is calculating the cube of 5 as 124**.

Interestingly I am getting the **correct answer(125)** when I use the power function to calculate the cube of 5 in a separate, simple program.

I also checked the code given here -->https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/check-armstrong-number which is also giving the wrong output. The answers to the somewhat similar questions that I found on this website didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Generally speaking, do not use floating-point functions (such as `pow`) for integer calculations, and especially not for number-theory-related problems.  If you choose to ignore this advice, then at least be sure to `round()` results to the nearest integer where that is appropriate.

Comment: If I run the program with 153 as input, I get the result: `153 is an armstrong number`. Seems correct to me.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for this. Use an integer type. You can write x^N as a simple loop using integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not able to reproduce the said problem. I do get the correct result for input 153, i.e. that it is an Armstrong number.

It could be some floating point rounding error due to use of `pow` (though I would find that strange in this specific case).

For a task like this one, you should **not** use floating point. Use the largest integer type available. Not only do you avoid nasty rounding errors but you also increases the range of input values that your program can handle.

So, I like to address this part:

> I cannot use t* t*t as this program is for Armstrong numbers of "n" digits, and not only 3

You can easily write a function that calculates `t^n` using integer math. Here is an example:

```
#include<inttypes.h>

uint64_t intpow(uint64_t t, uint64_t p)
{
    uint64_t result = 1;
    while(p>0)
    {
        result = result * t;
        --p;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notice: In its current form the function lacks overflow detection as I wanted to keep the function simple.

Answer (score 0):

There are Two ways to solve. 
1) Use round() function which will give the nearest integer (because there is some error in floating point calculation in codeblocks).

2) Declare your sum variable as float or double because then it will convert into perfect floating point precision.